# Make array of numbers in one cell in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to store some numbers in one cell (as an array)?
Please see below:

cell A1: `4,4,3,4,1,3,3,4`

cell A2: `5`  (5th element of array)

cell A3: `546254` (constant for this month)

cell A4: `=(MAX(A1)-INDEX(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},A1),1,A2))  *  (A3/SUM(A1))` (here 63029)

The formula of cell A4 causes error. Only way to solve it changing it as below:

cell A4: `=(MAX(4,4,3,4,1,3,3,4)-INDEX(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},4,4,3,4,1,3,3,4),1,A2))  *  (A3/SUM(4,4,3,4,1,3,3,4))`

So, I should write whole array in formula. I don't want to use VBA and Named Ranges.

Comment: A cell can not hold an array.  It can hold a number or a string or an error.  you will need to parse the string to create an array in the formula itself.

Comment: do you have FILTERXML? that is one way to parse the string into an array. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:

With the new dynamic array formula TEXTSPLIT() we can shorten this:

```
=LET(arr,TEXTSPLIT(A1,","),MAX(arr)-INDEX(arr,,A1)*(A3/SUM(arr))
```

---

Original

A cell can not hold an array. It can hold a number or a string or an error. you will need to parse the string to create an array in the formula itself.

using [FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml) to create an array from a string:

```
=(MAX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))-FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s["&A2&"]"))  *  (A3/SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

[image]

If one does not have FILTERXML:

```
=(MAX(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))-INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),A2))  *  (A3/SUM(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99))))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode

[image: k]

Comment: Thanks, my Excel version is 2010 and it don't has FILTERXML function.

Comment: @AliM67 see edit.  make sure to use Ctrl-Shift-enter to confirm the formula.