# kendo grid - array data not showing in the excel format after download in angular 8?

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, angular8, export-to-excel

I have to implement **Export to Excel** functionality via kendo-grid in angular single value data is printed but in case of array its not rendering the array value in excel after export can anybody let me how to fix that issue check below attached image for issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Need to process that data beforehand e.g. array.join(", ")

Comment: @mgraham but its return a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array.can you tell mw what the difference?

Comment: This way you will get an entry in the excel spreadsheet e.g. "Writer, Add, Red, Tag" instead of nothing

There's no a way I know of stuffing an array into one cell as a naturally composite object - each cell holds just one value - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727770/make-array-of-numbers-in-one-cell-in-excel

The alternative is to have a column per possible tag and that'd be a lot of work